# How to merge this 2 SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to obtain the first date each card was used.

I have this SQLs

```
SELECT distinct card from liq where dateF between '2016-06-09 10:00:00' and '2016-07-09 12:00:00' 

select top 1 * from liq where card = 1129535097095808 order by dateF asc
```

In the first one I obtain the cardNumber of each card. In the second one I have to find first date of each one but I don't know how to merge this two SQLs because if I use ' card in ( query1) it will return only the first of all this rows.

Anybody could help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but not the fastest:

```
select top 1 * from liq where card in (SELECT distinct card from liq where dateF between '2016-06-09 10:00:00' and '2016-07-09 12:00:00' ) order by dateF asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try to do this in one query, like this

```
Select [card], MIN(dateF) over (partition by [card] order by DateF) from liq
    where dateF between '2016-06-09 10:00:00' and '2016-07-09 12:00:00'
group by [card]
```

So you get a card number, and first date it was used

EDIT: Query wasn't tested, but give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CARD ORDER BY dateF) RN
        from liq 
        where dateF between '2016-06-09 10:00:00' and '2016-07-09 12:00:00'
)
SELECT CARD
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM(SELECT distinct t1.card FROM liq t1 WHERE t1.dateF BETWEEN '2016-06-09 10:00:00' AND '2016-07-09 12:00:00') t2, liq t3 WHERE t2.card=t3.card ORDER BY t2.dateF ASC
```

try this